# Is there any page which provides Syntax and explanations for Helper Form of play framework?

Tags: playframework

I actually looking forward to learn Syntax to develop pages using HelperForm in playFrame Work for Creating Forms. I don't get Syntax any where to create a dropdown box which gets values from a table in Data Base.

Answer (score 0):

To make a dropdown, use the `select` form helper and pass a sequence of options:

```
@select(yourForm("fieldname"),
  options = ...)
```

You must set options depending on your requirements (often `yourlist.map(x => x.toString -> x.toString)` is enough).

Build the list in your controller and then pass it to your view.